# Best place to ask question about different usage of Surface Pro3

Tags: support, site-recommendation

as above. Simple. Particularly how to use Surface Pro 3 as a 2nd monitor only. not as a surface pro itself. i.e. I have a laptop and use surface pro as a second monitor.

Comment: superuser.com ..